# Parse.com JS API - wildcard search

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have been searching and I can't find any instruction on how to create a simple wildcard search that will search all fields in a class.

For example I have a listing like:

```
Title: New Listing 

State: Florida 

City: Joe
```

If the user searches: "Listing Florida"

The above listing would be included in the results.

Please let me know what you think!

thanks, Mitch

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to take each string in your input ("Listing Florida" -> ["Listing", "Florida"]) and then search using a big `and` with lots of `or` parts. It is an ugly query.

It would be easier if you copied the text of every searchable field into a field called SearchDump or something (you could do this in your Cloud Code afterUpdate or something), then you could just do this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(MyClass);
for (var word in wordList) {
    query.contains('SearchDump', word);
}
```